# Garbage character from query under 32-bit OS, fine in 64-bit

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-c++, oledb

C++, OLEDB, running a query that returns 2 columns: an int and a varchar(50).

So I want to put it in

```
struct OutputData
{
    int      intID;
    wchar_t* lpszName;      
} outputData;
```

So, I bind

```
    m_oleDBUtils.CreateDBBindings(true, &pRowsetBindings[0], 1, 
        offsetof(OutputData, intID), 4, DBTYPE_I4, 0, 
        DBPARAMIO_NOTPARAM);
    m_oleDBUtils.CreateDBBindings(false, &pRowsetBindings[1], 2, 
        offsetof(OutputData, lpszName), 50, DBTYPE_WSTR | DBTYPE_BYREF, 0, 
        DBPARAMIO_NOTPARAM);
```

Etc. etc.

I build for Win32. Under Windows 7 x64 (running the 32-bit DLL!), it works. Under Windows XP x86, I get consistent garbage in the first two characters (with the rest of the string being fine). So instead of

```
One
Two
Three
```

I see

```
XXe
XXo
XXree
```

Again, the garbage value is the same for all records. I thought it was alignment, but /Zp2, /Zp4, /Zp8 and /Zp16 all show the same behavior.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have my doubts about that DLL being 32-bit.

Comment: @AJG85: You can't load a 64-bit dll into the space of a 32-bit process and vice-versa, so if it weren't it would crash.

Comment: You can't load a 32bit dll into a 64bit process either. You can however mess things up but mixing and matching.

Comment: If the DLL was not 32-bit, it would not run on 32-bit XP at all. So I'm fairly confident the image is, in fact, 32-bit.

Comment: @AJG85: Who said anything about a 64bit process? The OP states that he builds for Win32, so it should be a 32bit process, perfectly valid for loading the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to client-owned memory and /Zp1 fixed it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how you fixed it? I am having a similar problem but switching /Zp1 did not fix it.

Comment: Fiddle with where you get the buffers from; if I recall correctly I was using Windows APIs which under XP were never 1-aligned, switching to allocating from C++ did it. Then again, it's been a good, long while and I am NOT opening this dog up for you, sorry :-)